# How to define multi type as one type in golang

Tags: go, grammar

```
func GetFailedReasonAndErr (xxx) (string, error){
...
}

func AnyFailed (args ...(string, error)) {
   for _, arg := range args {
      if arg.error != nil {
         return arg
       }
   }
}

func main () {
    reason, err := AnyFailed(GetFailedReasonAndErr(yyy), GetFailedReasonAndErr(zzz))
    println(reason, err)
}
```

code above is unable to be complied, because "args ...(string, error)" is not allowed.
can I define (string, error) as one type ? or any better way ?(may use struct?)
like :
type reasonAndError (string, error)

Comment: Your sample code doesn't compile but that isn't the main problem with your question. The main problem is your question doesn't make any sense. Neither the `string` or `error` type have an `error` attribute. You can use the recently introduced ability to write generic functions and types in the [Go reference spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec) but that would not make your example valid. I suggest rewriting your question to show us a complete, minimal, example of what you want to do without the use of generics. From that we can suggest how to do the same thing in a generic manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I define (string, error) as one type ?

No, not with that syntax. Go does not have *tuples*.

> (may use struct?) like : type reasonAndError (string, error)

Yes, declare a struct type and use that. The syntax for declaring struct types is as follows:

```golang
type reasonAndError struct {
    reason string
    err    error
}
```

Then, to use it, you can do:

```golang
func GetFailedReasonAndErr(xxx) reasonAndError {
    // ...
}

func AnyFailed(args ...reasonAndError) (string, error) {
   for _, arg := range args {
      if arg.err != nil {
         return arg.reason, arg.err
       }
   }
   return "", nil
}

func main () {
    reason, err := AnyFailed(GetFailedReasonAndErr(yyy), GetFailedReasonAndErr(zzz))
    println(reason, err)
}
```